# Move files without conflicts

Tags: windows-10, file-transfer

I have many files in `folder1` and I would like to move them to `folder2`. There are a small number of files already in `folder2` (a hundred compared to several thousand in `folder1`) and I would like to move all files from `folder1` to `folder2` except when there is a file name conflict. (At that point I'll examine the remaining files individually and skip/modify/replace as needed.)

Is there a good way to do this? I'm on Windows 10 but I can use bash via MinGW if it's more convenient.

This is like [Batch File Copy and Move without overwriting](https://superuser.com/q/724184/56044) except that it involves thousands of files instead of a single file.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 The accepted answer moves only a single file, which is very different from my use case. (I wouldn't mind being closed as a duplicate but that doesn't seem like a duplicate to me.)

Comment: From the accepted answer: "Interestingly, it seems to work with wildcards as well." which it should. :)

Comment: I don’t understand the issue with the issue. x) Explorer should move and prompt you when it arrives at a file that exists at the target location. You would then choose not to move it and also apply that action to all queries of the same kind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I want to move all files from folder1 to folder2 unless there is a file name conflict.

Use the following batch file (located in the parent directory of `folder1` and `folder2`.

**MovesFiles.cmd:**

```
@echo off 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f %%f in ('dir /b folder1') do (
  if not exist folder2\%%~nxf move folder1\%%~nxf folder2 
  )
endlocal
```

Notes:

- Any files where there is a name conflict (ie already exist in `folder2`) are left in `folder1`.
- All other files are moved.

**Example usage:**

```
F:\test>dir /b folder1
1.txt
2.txt
3.txt
4.txt
5.txt

F:\test>dir /b folder2
2.txt
4.txt

F:\test>MoveFiles.cmd
        1 file(s) moved.
        1 file(s) moved.
        1 file(s) moved.

F:\test>dir /b folder1
2.txt
4.txt

F:\test>dir /b folder2
1.txt
2.txt
3.txt
4.txt
5.txt
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [dir](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) - Display a list of files and subfolders.
- [parameters](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) - A command line argument (or parameter) is any value passed into a batch script.